# NiFi - How to get listing of directories and organize them by name then obtain files from each directory?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to figure out how to perform the following steps within NiFi.

1. Obtain listing of directories from a specific location e.g. /my_src (Note the folders that will be appearing within here will be dated e.g. 20211125)
2. Based off of the listing obtained I need to sort the folders by date
3. For each folder then I need to GetFile from that directory
4. Then sort those files by their names

I am stuck at step 1 on finding a processor that pulls the directory names. I only see GetFile and List file.

Reason for this is that I need to process the folders based on the oldest to newest.

I would expect to be using a regex pattern to locate the valid folders that match the date format and ignore the other folders. Then with those values found pass them along sorted to another process that would get files from that path location, which GetFile does not seem to allow me to set dynamically.

Am I to approach this process differently within NiFi?

Comment: edjm any luck regarding this?

Comment: @filip No luck on this. I ended up moving all existing folders and files out to an archive folder and then when new data does come in, it gets processed and then moved out to the archive. This way the only thing that would be in the main folder are things to be processed and I don't have to try and find a way to sort them.